# How to make a page access Forbidden with a hook under CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i've got some issues to make my input page forbidden under CI. According to the rank of the user connected, he will be able to see or not the input page.
This is my hook in application/hooks/forbidden.php:

```
 <?php
class forbid
{
    private $CI;
        function forbidden()
        {
               if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            foreach ($this->session->userdata('ranked_in') as $rank)
            {
                switch ($rank)
                 {
                    case $rank== 1:     //Admin
                        redirect('home', 'refresh');
                        break;


                     case $rank== 4:    //student
                     {
                        if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == '/project/input')
                        {
                            redirect ('student','refresh');
                        }
                     }
                        break;
                 }
            }

         }else{
        $this->load->helper(array('form'));
        $this->load->view('login');
         }

        }

}
?>
```

My wish here was to redirect to the student page when the rank's user is 4  ,but nothing happens when i test it. Did i do mistakes or missunderstood something? Thanks for your help !

EDIT:
Hook is Enabled in the config file.
The Hook point in config/hooks:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Hooks
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you define "hooks" to extend CI without hacking the core
| files.  Please see the user guide for info:
|
|   https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html
|
*/

$hook['pre-controller'] = array(
        'class' => 'forbid',
        'function' => 'forbidden',
        'filename' =>  'forbidden',
        'filepath' =>   'hooks',
        'params' => array()

    );

?>
```

Comment: And what is the hook point? hooks is enabled?

Comment: i think that the problem is in the **base of switch** cuz the case is not `case $rank == 1:` the correct way is `case 1:`

Comment: @elddenmedio Hmm not necessarily usually the both syntax works for me...

Comment: However I've more doubts about the code in the case $rank = 4

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to see without the full picture of your code. Here is how I do it on one of my latest projects.

This code goes into /application/config/hooks.php - perhaps you can copy and adapt it to suit your needs.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Hooks
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you define "hooks" to extend CI without hacking the core
| files.  Please see the user guide for info:
|
|   https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html
|
*/

// Force Login
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = function()
{

    $CI =& get_instance();

    $publicPages = array(
        'debug',
        'login',
        'logout',
        'password-reset',
        'api',
        'api/3D-complete',
        'api/refund',
        'api/3D-enrolment-check'
    );

    $publicRegexPages = array(
        'password-reset-verification',
        'psp',
        'cron'
    );

    if(!$CI->session->userdata('isLoggedIn') && !in_array($CI->uri->uri_string, $publicPages) && !in_array($CI->uri->segment(1), $publicRegexPages))
    {

        $intendedPage = $CI->uri->uri_string;

        redirect('login?redirect=' . $intendedPage);

    }

};
```